# Programmatically direct to a specific HttpPost

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http-post

I have a web app in which I attempt to download invoices to a client's accounting system. The download request fires off an `HttpGet` which returns a PartialViewResult to display the quantity and amount of invoices selected for download. The current `HttpPost` returns a FilePathResult, which is a formatted file the client uses to import invoices into the system.

I now have a client who wants the file sent through an API, which would directly import the invoices into their system. This supplants the need to return a file.

Is there a way to direct the `HttpGet` to either run the `HttpPost FilePathResult` or the `HttpPost Void` (no file returned) without a bunch of jQuery IF statements on the PartialViewResult page?

Comment: I may have misstated my question. What I really need to know is how does one designate which HttpPost is run? Is there a way to say "When I click submit, I'd rather run the Post that returns nothing instead of the one that returns a file".

Note: I've already written and am running code to create the webrequest to the API and that works fine, returning a text file containing an error report if there are any. I'm trying to avoid returning that error file for this client and instead want to just refresh the page (though that's not really part of the question).

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically create a client to call a web service; in your case you can do something like the following:

```
var req = WebRequest.Create("http://someurl");
req.Method = "POST";
WritePostDataToStream(yourdatafile, req.GetRequestStream())
```

you need to write the method WritePostDataToStream(), in which you will write the bytes to the stream.

You would finish with req.GetResponse(), which completes the request and gets the response.

Comment: Use `HttpClient`; it's much better.